# Using Phonegap's console.log in separate html files

Tags: cordova

I am struggling to print to the Xcode console using console.log.

It works perfectly fine from index.html, but it doesn't work from other html files.

I might be able to solve this issue by using a single html file, but wanted to know if there's a way to fix this while using separate html files ? (I am using Phonegap 2.1.0, Jquery Mobile 1.2.0 and Xcode 4.3.3)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by moving my code to the index.html file. Sadly, it just didn't work in separate html files.

Answer (score 0):

`phonegap.js` captures `console.log` calls and invokes native debug statements to display in Xcode. Make sure you are including phonegap.js in other html files too. If you are loading the other pages using jquery mobile's ajax loading, then there could be some other issue.